# animation not working on firefox even though polyfill is added

Tags: css, angular, animation

I have this code for my route transitions:

```
function slideToLeft() {
  return trigger('routerTransition', [
    state('void', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    state('*', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}

function slideToTop() {
  return trigger('routerTransitionTop', [
    state('void', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    state('*', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%'
    })),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}),
      animate('1s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}),
      animate('1s ease-in-out',
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

I added this https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

With:

> npm install web-animations-js

And added it to polyfills.ts:

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

However the transition is not working.

How can I make the animation work in Firefox? I'm using Angular v2.

Comment: I was using a *-wildcard-selector on padding, which apparently firefox did not like (despite the polyfill).